# how to find a property of a list and print it c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

Hi I have a list of grades which has students' names and their grades. I want to find the top student and print out his/her name and show it in the output. Here is my code

```
double maxgrade = grades.Max(t => t.value);
Console.WriteLine("the top student is : \n");
var topgrade = grades.Where(r => r.value == maxgrade);
Console.WriteLine(grades.Select(r=>r.studentinfo.name));
```

but it doesn't work. My list name contains grades with properties of studentinfo, courseinfo, value and unit of the grade. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How specifically does this not work?  Which line fails?  How does it fail?

Comment: maybe it `Console.WriteLine(topgrade.Select(r=>r.studentinfo.name));`

Comment: it gives me a line like "system.linq.enumerable..." in the output

Comment: @SaraMolavi check the answer, that should work

Comment: @SaraMolavi: Are you trying to print out the entire enumerable, or just a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `select` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. The `Select` returns a collection of items, even if only 1 item matches the predicate it is still a collection. When you print it you get the `ToString()` of `IEnumerable<T>` instead of what you actually want which is the value inside.

However, I think you can achieve what you are doing in a better way:

```
var name = grades.OrderByDescending(t => t.value)
                 .FirstOrDefault()?.studentinfo.name;

Console.WriteLine(name);
```

If have a few students with the highest grade and you want to print all those that have the highest grade:

```
var names = grades.GroupBy(item => item.value)
                  .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
                  .Select(group => group.Select(item => item.studentInfo.name))
                  .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", names));
```

Comment: @SaraMolavi - you are welcome :) I has a problem with the second part and fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have filtered using top grade so you need to print out from the filtered collection which is `topgrade`. So change the query

```
Console.WriteLine(topgrade.Select(r=>r.studentinfo.name).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: it gives me a line like "system.linq.enumerable..." in the output

Comment: @SaraMolavi did you check my updated answer ? does it giving the same wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

Using Zip:

```
var firstStudent = grades.Select(x => x.value).Zip(grades.Select(y => y.studentinfo.name), 
(value, name) => new { Name = name, Value = value}).OrderBy(z => z.Value).ToList().First();

Console.WriteLine(firstStudent.Value + " " + firstStudent.Name);
```

Comment: Why the hell you'd want to do it like this, when you could do it as easy as in @GiladGreen answer? :)

Comment: @Pikoh I just like Zip, and I really think that it matches here, where you will need to group both the name of the student and it's grade. What do you think, is it overkill or what? Of course: or what :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FirstOrDefault()` method afther calling the last `Select()`. The reason is because of the output of select method which is an `IEnumerable<T>`. For more information refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx).